# Display user's Google Calendar (PHP)

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I've made an application where a user can add event in his Google Calendar thanks to a form. I use Oauth2 Authentication and Google Calendar API (in PHP).
Now I would like to display user's calendar when the user is connected with his Google Account. Can i use an iframe, or another solution to do that?

Comment: An iframe to `calendar.google.com` should work?

Comment: I can display my own calendar in an iframe, but i don't know how display user's calendar in an iframe :/

Comment: This page should help. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts

Comment: `calendar.google.com` will display the current logged in users google calendar... Because that is the URL people use to look at their calendar....

Comment: We need a calendarId to use an iframe to calendar.google.com, where can i find it?

Answer (score 1):

In fact the CalendarID is the user's mail.
So, it works:

```
$oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$userinfo = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
$emailUser = $userinfo->getEmail();
print_r($emailUser);

$emailUserCal=str_replace ('@','%40',$emailUser);
print_r($emailUserCal);
```

We need to replace the '@' by '%40' in the url.

In my form:

```
<?php echo '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=' . $emailUserCal . '&amp;color=%232952A3&amp;ctz=Europe%2FParis" style=" border-width:0 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>' ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass user mail id which one you want to show calendar.

In PHP:

```
$userEmail = "test@gmail.com";

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=' . $userEmail . '&amp;color=%232952A3&amp;ctz=Europe%2FParis" style=" border-width:0 " width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

In Js:

```
let userEmail = "test@gmail.com";

 let calendarIfram = '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=' + userEmail + '&amp;color=%232952A3&amp;ctz=Europe%2FParis" style=" border-width:0 " width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>';
```

Comment: I have used this this is showing calendar in my website but it is not editable nor can I add events to the date